# Using import with a level specification isn't supported by AccessControl: _warnings

Tags: plone

I'm having problem with FS controller page template. I had this Plone2 base product which i have eggified while doing Plone 4.2 migration. I have pasted traceback below.

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerPageTemplate, line 91, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.BaseControllerPageTemplate, line 26, in _call
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FormController, line 384, in validate
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module Products.CMFFormController.FSControllerValidator, line 58, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFFormController.Script, line 145, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 130, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 32, in exams_list
   - <FSControllerValidator at /dev/exam/online/booking/validators/exams_list>
   - Line 32
  Module AccessControl.ZopeGuards, line 299, in guarded_import
Unauthorized: Using import with a level specification isn't supported by AccessControl: _warnings
```

line 32 on exams_list validators is wrap with astric

```python
if event and not state.getErrors():
  try:
     context.script.validateEvent()
  except ValueError,exc: 
     state.setError('SIMSError',str(exc))
  **except 'dryrun':**
     state.setStatus('dryrun')
```

Any help or pointer always helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for string exceptions was removed from Python 2.6; you'll need to use a proper exception class for `'dryrun'` instead.

You'll need to mark that exception as importable by restricted code before you can then import it into your Controller Script.

Here is an example definition for such an exception:

```py
from AccessControl.SecurityInfo import ModuleSecurityInfo

security = ModuleSecurityInfo('My.Product.exceptions')

security.declarePublic('DryRunException')
class DryRunException(Exception):
    '''The process was not committed, this was only a dry run'''
```

With the `ModuleSecurityInfo` information in place you can now import this exception into your script:

```py
from My.Product.exceptions import DryRunException
```

and catch that instead in your `except` block; the code that throws this exception will need to be updated too, of course.